# Reasons not to use boolean instead of void?

Tags: java

What are the reasons to use void instead of boolean?
Ok, in most cases i dont need the return value, but are there real disatvantages if i use boolean instead of void in general? (except GC Collection etc.)

Hope anyone can help me with this more "philosophical" question

Comment: If your method has boolean return type, you have to return a boolean from it. If you don't want to have to put pointless `return false` or `return true` statements all over your code, it is useful to have `void` return type as an option.

Comment: Why do you want to use `boolean` if your method does not return anything?

Comment: this is a nice one to read about this philosophical debate -> http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/11724/is-it-better-practice-to-have-void-method-throw-an-exception-or-to-have-the-meth

Comment: If the method doesn't need to return anything use `void`. If it needs to return a boolean, use `boolean`. Am I correct in thinking that your question is mainly for methods that do the following: `someMethod(){ // do something with the possibility to fail; return true if successful, false otherwise }`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

using `boolean` doesn't trigger garbage, or a performance overhead of any size.

Returning a value which isn't intended to be used is just confusing. If you see a method which returns a value, you don't want to asking yourself; how should I use this value correctly, when in reality there is no point to the value.  Conversely you don't want to get in the habit of ignoring return values because they are usually returned for a good reason.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about possible disadvantages in generated byte code performance, but in general, it's more clear to understand API when it reacts as it reads.

If I see method with name `void addPositionToOrder(Position position);` I understand what kind of action will be performed if I invoke it.

If I see `boolean addPositionToOrder(Position position);` I don't really know what will be returned because for me, this action shouldn't return me any response. So I'll have to go to javadoc/reference/other and read about it.

If you want to indicate some error occured inside your `addPositionToOrder(Position position);` method, use [Exceptions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/) rather than return code.